# Export Google Apps Script result to Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I have this script which extracts the current number of used licenses to the log file. We want to run the script daily to build up a pattern of usage.
I cant figure out how to save / export the results of the script to a Google Sheet however. Can anyone help?

```
function getNumberOfLicenses() {
  var tryDate = new Date();
  var dateString = tryDate.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (tryDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + tryDate.getDate().toString();
  while (true) {
    try {
      var response = AdminReports.CustomerUsageReports.get(dateString,{parameters : "accounts:gsuite_unlimited_total_licenses,accounts:gsuite_unlimited_used_licenses"});
      break;
    } catch(e) {
      //Logger.log(e.warnings.toString());
      tryDate.setDate(tryDate.getDate()-1);
      dateString = tryDate.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (tryDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + tryDate.getDate().toString();
      continue;
    }
  };
  var availLicenseCount = response.usageReports[0].parameters[0].intValue;
  var usedLicenseCount = response.usageReports[0].parameters[1].intValue;
  Logger.log("Available licenses:" + availLicenseCount.toString());
  Logger.log("Used licenses:" + usedLicenseCount.toString());
  return availLicenseCount;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There's no attempt in this script to write anything to a sheet.

Comment: If you didn't this yet please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getNumberOfLicenses() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID"); // Sheet where you want to write the result.

  var tryDate = new Date();
  var dateString = tryDate.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (tryDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + tryDate.getDate().toString();
  while (true) {
    try {
      var response = AdminReports.CustomerUsageReports.get(dateString,{parameters : "accounts:gsuite_unlimited_total_licenses,accounts:gsuite_unlimited_used_licenses"});
      break;
    } catch(e) {
      //Logger.log(e.warnings.toString());
      tryDate.setDate(tryDate.getDate()-1);
      dateString = tryDate.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (tryDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + tryDate.getDate().toString();
      continue;
    }
  };
  var availLicenseCount = response.usageReports[0].parameters[0].intValue;
  var usedLicenseCount = response.usageReports[0].parameters[1].intValue;
  Logger.log("Available licenses:" + availLicenseCount.toString());
  Logger.log("Used licenses:" + usedLicenseCount.toString());

  ss.appendRow([availLicenseCount.toString(), usedLicenseCount.toString()]) // Adding a row with the data in the first two columns of the sheet.

  return availLicenseCount;
}
```

This code will open the sheet you want (you'll need its ID) and it will add the data to it at the end of the code. The two variables will be added to the first two cells of the next empty rows. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) you'll find documentation and guides on how to use the SpreadsheetApp.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!